# Open buffer with ftplugin file for current filetype?

Tags: vim, code-snippets, ftplugin

I found no answers or questions to this after some Google searches, but hopefully somebody else might see the use for this aswell.

I think it would be quite nice to have as you come up with new filetype specific `iabbrevs` as you are working. Then you can quickly add it to your `filetype.vim`-file in the `ftplugin` directory without having to start looking at filetypes and spending time pulling up the correct ftplugin file.

I am not that good at customizing vim yet, but if someone can give some pointers that would be cool.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understood it correctly, you want a way to edit the corresponding `ftplugin` to the buffer you're working on. You can get the filetype with the expression `&filetype`, so one way to do it is to get this in a command with <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> and <kbd>=</kbd> (insert from the expression register, see help files for `c_CTRL-R`)

```
:e ~/.vim/ftplugin/<C-R>=&filetype<CR>.vim<CR>
```

This can be easily converted into a map to be placed in your .vimrc:

```
nnoremap <leader>ef :e ~/.vim/ftplugin/<C-R>=&filetype<CR>.vim<CR>
```

Or a command:

```
com! EditFTPlugin exe 'e ~/.vim/ftplugin/' . &filetype . '.vim'
```